# Start instance while AMI is being created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I created an image from an AWS instance which is pending. Then, I plan to create a instance clone from the image.
But, my question is: Is it safe to start the original instance from which I created the image, while the image is in 'pending' status?

Comment: Does it actually let you try that? I assume it would just give you an error.

Comment: I did it and it worked, but I want to know if it is correct and I don't want to get an error in the future.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood the question. It's totally safe to restart the original instance after the AMI creation process has begun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have called `ec2:CreateImage` and it has given you your AMI ID, it is safe to restart the original EC2 instance.

The AMI image and associated EBS snapshots will be created point-in-time as of when the `ec2:CreateImage` command was executed.

However, until the EBS snapshots are complete, you may notice that the EBS volumes are "sluggish".

Comment: Do you know how this is achieved? The old VM (source of the AMI) should use a disk which has some sort of Snapshot point + Diffs.

Comment: It's based on how EBS volumes and EBS snapshots are implemented under the hood. Only AWS knows the full details.